# How to avoid duplicate inserts in stored procedure inside loop

Tags: postgresql

I have a case in which I am struggling to get the expected result from the stored procedure in which two insert operations are executed. The second insert is dependent on the result (`id`) from the first insert. However, the result is duplicated - each record is inserted twice.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.field_validations2(
  )
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   cust_rec RECORD;
  new_signature_id integer;
   inconsideration varchar;
BEGIN
  inconsideration := 'IN_CONSIDERATION';
    FOR cust_rec IN
        EXECUTE format('SELECT l.* FROM public.report_attached_person_many_to_many l INNER JOIN public.report r ON l.report_id = r.id WHERE r.report_status=%L', inconsideration)
    LOOP
  INSERT INTO public.report_signature(
  id, active, created, created_by, deleted, modified, modified_by, comment, status, type, staff)
  VALUES (nextval('hibernate_sequence'),'true','1561713543512', '10000001', 'false', '1561713543512', '10000001', '', '0', '1' , cust_rec.staff_id)
  RETURNING id into new_signature_id;
  INSERT INTO public.report_required_signatures_many_to_many(
    report_id, signature_id)
    VALUES (cust_rec.report_id, new_signature_id);
    END LOOP;
END
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.field_validations2()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: I would guess that you are getting duplicate inserts because the query that drives your loop is returning duplicate results.  That join probably matches on multiple rows.

Comment: If i remove second insert, it is not duplicating? how abt that? @Jeremy

Comment: Perhaps there are triggers that do something you don't expect?

Comment: You should come up with a reproducible test case that exhibits the problem, else we are reduced to guessing.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe what u mean reproducible test case ? this is a good case? u select from inner join and loop through the result and get id #1 that I am inserting first insert operation and from this got returning ID which will be the input for the second insert ?

Comment: Consider this as a case just create three tables create inner join and insert like I did and u will see the result mb ?

Comment: We need an SQL script that creates tables, inserts some data, defines and calls the function and produces a result like you describe.